# Float an image next to a table in GitHub-flavored Markdown

Tags: html, css, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

At the top of [this README.md](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/blob/8a837334b0d36830ce429b9ae6d8dc4b485a0926/README.md) (raw code at the top of [this page](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ropensci/drake/8a837334b0d36830ce429b9ae6d8dc4b485a0926/README.md)), I am trying to float an image next to a Markdown table. My efforts with the `float` style property and `align` attribute in `img` have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your document is hosted on GitHub you can't.

As documented in GitHub's [Markup](https://github.com/github/markup#github-markup) library, after the Markdown is converted to HTML, the...

> HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as `script` tags, inline-styles, and `class` or `id` attributes. See the [sanitization filter](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb) for the full whitelist.

In other words, anything you include in the Markdown to "style" your document (`style` tags, inline-styles, etc.) will be stripped out by the sanitizer. If you want control over the look and styling of your documents, then you need to host them somewhere where you have complete control. GitHub is not that place.

Answer (score 0):

your table has `width:100%` and won't let any elements besides. try changing its width to `width :auto` and display from block to `display:inline-block`. also, change the image container to `display:inline-block`

Comment: I would really like to do that, but the table is written in markdown, not directly in html. How do I style a markdown table?

Comment: @landau : put the table markup inside a div and add this CSS to the container div.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately, the table does not render and the CSS is ignored.